# Function availability and configuration errors: The 'Tabular View' function is not included in the standard (64-bit) edition of Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have created a Cube in Visual Studio 2017.
SSMS Version 12.0.6118.4
Dimension gets processed successfully, Cube also gets processed successfully.
But while creating the tabular view in browser of visual studio, I am facing following error:

Function availability and configuration errors: The 'Tabular View' function is not included in the standard (64-bit) edition of Analysis Services. (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Analysis Services).

Could anyone please help?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Your business only has Standard Edition. YOu need Enterprise edition to make use of the feature you want.

Comment: As you can see, Tabular models are only supported in Enterprise edition in SQL Server 2014: [BI Semantic Model (Tabular)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014#BISemModel_tabular)

Answer (score 0):

This combination of visual studio/SSMS versions and 2014 analysis services is known to cause a problem, as opposed to being an edition issue per se.

Upgrade your SSMS version to 18.3 or higher.

Comment: SSMS will make no difference to what is supported by the edition of SQL Server. Tabular models were an Enterprise only feature in SQL Server 2012 and 2014 (Some features were made available in standard in 2016+, and more again in 2019). Updating the version of SSMS won't change how your instance behaves.

Comment: @Larnu Per the OP, it's not a problem with the model. The cube was processed successfully. The issue the OP is having seems specifically to be with the browser. That's how I read the question, at least. [Reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167945/the-tabular-view-feature-is-not-included-in-the-64.html). We had a similar issue a few years ago.